# Error 1064 (42000) while creating a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, runtime-error, delimiter

I am getting the following error while trying to create a stored procedure.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1.
```

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE CRT_TBL(IN tablename VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
SET @table := tablename;
SET @sql_text := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@table,'(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,LOCATION VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "Delhi",PRIMARY KEY(ID))AUTO_INCREMENT=201;');
PREPARE stmt from @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
END $

DELIMITER ;

CALL CRT_TBL('DEPARTMENT');
```

Please help.

Comment: Your quotes are all wrong. Use `'`

Comment: @juergend I wrote this on word first before pasting on stack and that is why the quotes have an issue. The quotes used were `'` itself.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error - and there is no null anywhere in the published code so I don't see that the error is in the published code.

Comment: @P.Salmon try `CALL CRT_TBL("Department"); `

Comment: I did - no problem